# How to design a VAE for a given image dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, autoencoders

I have a dataset with texture images of the size 512x512. I tried to train a VAE with 3 "blocks" (Convolution , Activation and Batchnormalization) in the encoder and in the decoder and a bottleneck layer of the size 512.

The reconstructed images seemed really blurry and I was wondering if there is a guide out there which gives advises to designing these Layers for a given dataset. I do not really have a problem with the reconstructed images being blurry, I just do not really know if my designed VAE (and the layers that I used) did a "good enough" job.

I would really appreciate if somebody can give me some advise on this!

Comment: What are the activation functions, loss function and batch size you're using?

Comment: I use ReLu as the activation function, my total loss consists of the reconstruction loss (where I use the reduced mean of the binary crossentropy of the reconstruction in comparison to the original image which is then multiplied by the image size 512x512) and the Kullback-Leibler loss. I use a batch size of 16 for training.

Comment: This thread has some good info on blurry outputs from VAE models, https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/9t712f/dwhy_are_images_created_by_gan_sharper_than/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=&utm_content=post_title

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, cross-entropy is used as the loss function.

Cross-entropy (the negative Bernoulli log-likelihood) is known for this blurry aspect.

The use of the Continuous Bernoulli (or other distributions, such as Beta) log-likelihood might ameliorate the issue. See [The continuous Bernoulli: fixing a pervasive error in variational autoencoders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06845).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! I think I should have formulated my issue a little more precisely. I dont really have a problem with the reconstructions being blurry, I just dont really know if my VAE did a "good job" and correspondingly if my Encoding/Decoding structure is  "good". I think a guide on designing these networks or an existing VAE-Network on similar image data would help me designing my own Layers in my VAE.